# Configuring cron using wp-cli on local server with Mamp Pro

Tags: cron, cli, mamp

I'm testing CiviCRM 4.7 in a WordPress 4.4.2 installation. I'm running this on a local server with Mac OSX 10.11.2 using MAMP Pro.

I'm trying to configure cron using the wp-cli method. I've installed, renamed and moved wp-cli and running `wp --info` in /Applications/MAMP/bin gives

PHP binary: /usr/bin/php
PHP version:    5.5.30
php.ini used:
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 0.22.0
Phils-MacBook-Air:bin phillip$

`wp help` shows the WordPress commands

I'm now trying to implement

```
/path/to/wp --user=<cron> --url=<http://example.com> --path=</path/to/wp> civicrm api job.execute auth=0
```

In my case I'm trying

```
/users/phillip/Sites/thetestsite.dev --user=<philnicholl> --url=<http://thetestsite.dev:8888> --path=</users/phillip/Sites/thetestsite.dev> civicrm api job.execute auth=0
```

but I get

-bash: philnicholl: No such file or directory

(philnicholl is my WordPress administrator username)

I know I'm missing something obvious.

I'm have experience with WordPress and Mamp Pro but am new to both CLI and CIVICRM. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Just checking - does your command literally include the '<', '>' around the user, url and path values?  If so, remove them - they are meant as placeholders in the example line.  Bash interprets them as stdin, stdout redirection.

Comment: Thank you. Running `/users/phillip/Sites/thetestsite.dev --user=philnicholl --url=http://thetestsite.dev:8888 --path=/users/phillip/Sites/thetestsite.dev civicrm api job.execute auth=0` I now get `-bash: /Users/phillip/Sites/thetestsite.dev: is a directory` I'm trying to follow these instructions: [https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-wp-climethod] Does the `/path/to/wp` in the instructions refer to the path to the root folder of the local site or to wp-cli.phar renamed as wp now in /usr/bin/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example wp-cli command I use that works:

```
/home/ubuntu/wp-cli/wp-cli --require=/home/ubuntu/wp-cli/civicrm.php --path=/var/www/wordpress civicrm api job.execute > /dev/null
```

I hope that helps!

UPDATE: I see your problem!  "/path/to/wp" means, "path to wp-cli, including wp-cli".  I completely looked past that part at the beginning, since that's not generally where the problems are found.

Usually, "wp-cli" is aliased to "wp" so it can automatically include the CiviCRM extension - but with cron, I usually just use the require directly.

So log into your computer and type `which wp-cli`.  Let's say it returns `/usr/bin/local/wp-cli`.  Replace ONLY the first path to WP with that, so it looks like:

To forestall your next question about why it doesn't work - the  is a placeholder, and the angle brackets should NOT be included in the actual statement.  Angle brackets are a common way in documentation of command-line programs to say, "insert your value here".  So instead of `<philnicoll>`, just write `philnicoll`.

You should be left with something like:

```
/usr/bin/local/wp-cli --user=philnicholl --url=http://thetestsite.dev:8888 --path=/users/phillip/Sites/thetestsite.dev civicrm api job.execute auth=0
```

Comment: Thank you, though I'm not exactly sure how to change your command to suit my case.

Comment: @philnicholl I just updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, Jon. I'd previously moved and renamed wp-cli as wp and moved it to /usr/bin - running `which wp` confirms this returning `/usr/bin/wp` . So I tried running `usr/bin/wp --user=philnicholl --url=http://thetestsite.dev:8888 --path=/users/phillip/Sites/thetestsite.dev civicrm api job.execute auth=0` and got `Error establishing a database connection` which seems like an improvement. Where now? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The wiki CIVICRM instructions for the wp-cli method do seem rather confusing in that /path/to/wp appears twice in the code but represents two different things and then in the following comments it says 'Replace </path/to/wp civicrm>' Presumably the last placeholder chevron is in the wrong place and should be after wp and not after civicrm.

Comment: I fixed the database connection problem following instructions here: http://laurenpittenger.com/wpcli-error-establishing-database-connection-mamp/ I had to unlock my bash profile using instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824493/my-bash-profile-is-locked-how-do-i-edit-it  All good now: Cron running OK. Thanks very much.